# "Export" vim syntax highlighting to output to shell?

Tags: vim, shell

Is there some program that can parse vim syntax highlighting scripts and colorize code for export to the shell?  Basically I am looking for cat/less with shell highlighting that draws its syntax from vimscript definitions, so I can define my own.

addendum: A preferred solution would be a program that outputted to stdout directly, like `cat`, so i could pipe to less or whatever i would want to use it for

Comment: I've never heard of something like that. But did you try {pygments](http://pygments.org/)?

Comment: @romainl I did look at pygments, but there is support for customization in the matter I am looking for

Answer (score 4):

For use as a pager, Vim comes with `$VIMRUNTIME/macros/less.sh`. See [here on the Vim Tips Wiki](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Using_vim_as_a_syntax-highlighting_pager). There's also a plugin alternative, [vimpager](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1723), and you'll probably find more on the Web.

Comment: This is nice and I will probably be using it :)  However it might be nice to have something that prints directly to stdout.

Answer (score 3):

I answered a [similar question on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13408134/utilizing-emacs-or-vims-syntax-highlighter-for-command-line-program):

Matthew Wozniski wrote a script called vimcat.sh that does this with Vim. His version is at https://github.com/godlygeek/vim-files/blob/master/macros/vimcat.sh. I've made a few modifications to it (if memory serves, the modifications allowed it to run on my Mac OS X system; I know the substitution of `/dev/fd/9` for `/proc/self/fd/9` had that purpose); see my gist at https://gist.github.com/4090959.

I believe both versions of the script have trouble with returning to default background color if Vim's highlighting changes the background.

Comment: Thank you for this, this is almost exactly what I was looking for :)  Do you know if it's possible to have this work with stdin?